# Magnolia CMS: hide links to denied pages

Tags: magnolia

I denied the web access to a web page for users with a specific role, through ACL. Now, when this users navigate the site can still see all the links to the denied page. How to hide these links?

Magnolia version: CE 4.5.8

thanks
Fabio

Answer (score 0):

a) Ask your question at the Magnolia help forum. Yu get more answers there. http://forum.magnolia-cms.com/forum/threads.html?forumId=caf52257-62a1-40c4-8da7-cefb66785062&page=1

b) What kind of link? You will not be able to change a link in a "Text and Image" (F)CkEditor component.

c) Extending ETKLinkTransformerManger might help

d) Look in internalLink.ftl of the STK

Comment: e) the navigation links are rendered in horizontalNavigation.ftl and verticalNavigation.ftl, extend NavigationItem with a method to check permission and f) you have to disable the Magnolia cache

Comment: I don't think that extending ETKLinkTransformerManager would help. All this class does is produce the url. You would need to modify the FTL to not generate the markup around the link (<a href="">...</a>) when url returned by transformer is empty.
Navigation should already render links to only those subpages that you have access to, but indeed you need to disable the cache for that.